# Cascaded dropdown is throwing away the "Please Select"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I've finally got a pair of cascading dropdowns working properly. Unfortunately, upon selecting an item in the first one, the second one loads and promptly throws away the null-value "Please Select". I have found how to insert a SelectListItem with Text="Please Select", Value="0" but I hesitate to do that. If possible, I'd like to use the built in null-value.

I've got all of this inside an auto-generated Controller & Views set, and am currently working on the Create page.

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Books/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AuthorID = new SelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorID", "AuthorName");
        //ViewBag.SeriesID = new SelectList(db.Series, "SeriesID", "SeriesName");
        ViewBag.SeriesID = new SelectList(db.Series.Where(v => v.SeriesID == 0), "SeriesID", "SeriesName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Books/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookID,BookName,AuthorID,SeriesID")] Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AuthorID = new SelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorID", "AuthorName", book.AuthorID);
        ViewBag.SeriesID = new SelectList(db.Series, "SeriesID", "SeriesName", book.SeriesID);
        return View(book);
    }

    public JsonResult GetSeries(int id)
    {
        SelectList list = new SelectList(db.Series.Where(v => v.AuthorID == id), "SeriesID", "SeriesName");

        return Json(new SelectList(db.Series.Where(v => v.AuthorID == id), "SeriesID", "SeriesName"));
    }
```

**View:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#AuthorID").change(function () {
            $("#SeriesID").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSeries")', // calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#AuthorID").val() },
                success: function (series) {
                    // contains the JSON formatted list passed from the controller
                    $.each(series, function (i, ser) {
                        $("#SeriesID").append('<option value="' + ser.Value + '">' + ser.Text + '</option>');
                    }); // adding option
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve series.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Book</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorID, "Author", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("AuthorID", null, "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SeriesID, "Series", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("SeriesID", null, "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SeriesID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

For whatever it may be worth, I also tried to figure out the cascade dropdowns in the following manner, but never got it to work. I'd thought that perhaps by following the format used in the 'public ActionResult Create()' method I might bypass the loss of the null-value.

I also thought to try crossing the two; call the controller method via Json & load via ViewBag but my understanding of the methods apparently isn't advanced enough to pull that off (if it's possible).

**Fail Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetSeries")]
public ActionResult GetSeries(int id)
{
    ViewBag.SeriesID = new SelectList(db.Series.Where(v => v.AuthorID == id), "SeriesID", "SeriesName");
    return View();
}
```

**Fail View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSeries", "Books", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "0" })) 
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorID, "Author", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AuthorID", null, "Please Select",
              htmlAttributes: new
              {
                  @class = "form-control",
                  onchange = "$('#AuthorID').submit()", 
                  name = "action:GetSeries" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()
{
     // All the other stuff from the view here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create it in the ajax function (calling `empty` clears **all** options so you need to add it back). Note also there is no *built in null-value*! The "Please Select" option as added by the html helper when you use the overload that accepts an `optionLabel` and your using ajax to re-populate the dropdownlist, not the html helper.

```
$("#AuthorID").change(function () {
  $("#SeriesID").empty().append($('<option></option>').text('Please select'));
  ...
```

Note, you do not need to create a select list in the `GetSeries()` method (its just unneccesary overhead)

```
public JsonResult GetSeries(int id)
{
  var data = db.Series.Where(v => v.AuthorID == id).Select(s => new
  {
    Value = s.SeriesID,
    Text = s.SeriesName
  }
    return Json(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my verbiage; wasn't quite sure what to call that. So the append() works beautifully. But my data is now showing up as 'undefined'. Is the empty() wiping something else I need to add back in? Also, does the empty() throw out literally everything except the ID?

Comment: No the issue is with the controller code. Its was not returning valid data (I've updated it - used a colon instead of a comma - ahhh). If it does not work, check that it works using your initial code. If that works, then debug the code I provided above to see if there are any other erros

Comment: I'd already noticed that and the extra ) in the return statement. Didn't fix it, and I tried it with my original code- no dice.

Comment: Ha, found it! in the View's javascript I had 'series.Text' and it needs to be 'ser.Text'. Thanks a bunch!